# making android application in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: android

I have installed eclipse juno on ubuntu 12.10. When I am trying to make a simple android project, it makes such a project:

```
package com.tanvi.alarm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

And there is a new folder called menu in the res folder also. I did not chose any menu option while giving the options for the project. What shall be done?

Comment: I'm confused what you are asking? Are you asking how to create a simple view to test?

Comment: i am asking how to get the simple generated project...that we get in windows..that is sans this onCreateOptionsMenu() method

Answer (score 1):

it's just default example with sample one item option menu (opened on a phone/emulator with menu button). If you don't need any options menu, just delete menu res folder and onCreateOptionsMenu method.
For more about menu, checkout [Menus tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: Lol, yea i mean its as simple as that. I think what happened was he clicked the wrong section, and a menu happened.

Comment: uhmm..its a "she"..and i went throught the entire process again.. i couldn't figure what i am doing wrong

Comment: I believe, Google just decided that options menu is default item in any application (usually it's so) and just added it to the latest Android tools examples by default. If You unselect 'Create Activity' checkbox while creating project, it won't create any menu and any activity.